# $HOME/.zshrc permission denied

Tags: flutter, sdk, zsh

i am trying to set the path for flutter and im following the guide at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path.

However, i get this error -> zsh: permission denied: /Users/roy/.zshrc

Does anybody have any solution to this?

Additionally, i have set Terminal Full Disk Access permission in Security & Privacy

[image]

Comment: `.zshrc` has already been sourced when the interactive shell starts. Sourcing it again immediately makes no sense.

Comment: The link you provide says to *edit* `.zshrc`, not run it.

Comment: @chepner i think the path i have set was wrong, may i ask how to edit that path again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run the file `.zshrc` as a command. This does not make sense, as this is a special file used by setting up an interactive Z-Shell. There is nothing which forbids you to do this, but I don't see any possible reason why someone wants to do it. In any case, **if** you want to do it, you need to set the execute permission on the file, as you do for any other command which you want to execute, i.e.

```
chmod +x ~/.zshrc
```

But as before, you really should think first whether this is indeed something you want to do.

If you want to evaluate its content inside your current zsh process, you can do a

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

In this case, you need only read-permission, no execute-permission.